# Syntax for arrays as operands

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

What is the syntax in order to pass an array that is not predefined in a function as operand?

For example, I have this function:

```
void kilos(int percentage[2], char liquid[2][4]);
```

So if I make two different arrays and pass them as operands everything work properly.
How can this work if I do not want to make the arrays before the call of the function?
Is the only solution to analyze the operands and not use arrays?

I want to call the function, but I want to make the arrays when I call the function something like:

```
kilos(int percent[2]={40,60}, char liq[2][4]={'wate','milk'})
```

Comment: For example i have this function:

    void kilos(int percentage[2],char liquid[2][4]);

Comment: What do you mean by "not predefined"? How do you "analyze the operands"?

Comment: Are you saying that you want those parameters to be optional?

Comment: i want to call the function but i want to make the arrays when i call the function something like:kilos(int percent[2]={40,60},char liq[2][4]={'wate','milk'})

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you mean that you want to accept arrays of *any* size? What do you mean by *I do not want to make the arrays before calling the function?* Do you want to create the objects internally?

Comment: the last one i know the variables but i do not want to make the arrays before i call the function.The arrays have certain size and i know it.

Comment: Why people are downvoting a valid question? Maybe OP didn't make it crystal clear, but it doesn't deserve the downvotes.

Comment: C or C++?  The answer will be different for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, if you have a C++11 capable compiler and you use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays, you could use [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists):

```
 void kilos(const std::vector<int> percentage,
            const std::vector<std::string> liquid);

// ...

kilos({40, 60}, {"water", "milk"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a pointer to a function is equivalent to passing an array.  The pointer can be to a statically allocated buffer, or dynamic memory (e.g. `new []` or `malloc`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function like this:

```
kilos((int[2]){40,60}, (char[2][4]){"wate", "milk"});
```

Note the double quotes around string literals. And you probably need second array to be `char[2][5]` to allow null terminator.